# ReviewBoard upload diff.txt

Tags: review-board

I use `git diff revision1 revision2>diff.txt` get diff.txt
and upload diff.txt to the ReviewBoard, but I get

```
The uploaded diff uses short revisions, but Review Board requires full revisions.
Please generate a new diff using the --full-index parameter.
```

1.there is no problem generating the diff.txt path,

2.local and ReviewBoard's code are the same.

Comment: I have solved the problem, make sure the ReviewBoard and local's code are the same.

Answer (score 0):

make sure the ReviewBoard and local's code are the same.